# Conventional Windows 7 Task manager vs Windows 8 Task manager

Tags: windows-8, task-manager

What is the big leap on the new task manager? Is this just a altered display that gives better overview of tasks happening inside the system, (or) is there really a big leap compared to the windows 7 task manager.

Seeing too much talk about this in the feature list made me ask this question !

Comment: Something to read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/10/13/the-windows-8-task-manager.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The "conventional" experience is basically the "Details" tab now.  The "Processes" tab groups by applications with Windows, has nesting, and exposes disk usage.  It also has relative coloring so you can easily spot applications with higher usage of resources.

In addition, there's now a "Startup" tab, which measures the performance impact of applications which startup with the machine, and easily allow you to disable them.

The "App History" tab allows you to see how things have been performing in general, without having them open right then.

The "Performance" tab shows more information and has the graphs more nicely organized and colored for quick scanning.  You can also right click and get the "Summary View" if you just want live charts.